# Async Job Processing based on PostgreSQL

Tags: open-source, python, server, postgresql, message-broker

I search an async job processing system like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [python-rq](http://python-rq.org/) but based on PostgreSQL.

Needed features:

- Async processing of jobs
- Uses PostgreSQL
- API for Python
- Store message in language independent format (json, yaml, protcol buffers, ...) NOT python pickle.
- open source

Why PostgreSQL:

- We already use postgreSQL
- Jobs most not get lost. This not the default of Redis and RabbitMQ.
- We only have few jobs per hour. Simplicity is more important than performance.
- Celery is too big

Related article about `SELECT FOR UPDATE .. SKIP LOCKED` which was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.5: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/

Answer (score 0):

This one does not solve all wanted features, but most of them:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-boss

It is based on node.js, not Python.

It uses PostgresSQL with the new [SKIP LOCKED](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/) feature.